# PayPal settings in Magento 1.7.0.2 won't save

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7

I am trying to save PayPal Payments Pro settings in Magento 1.7.0.2 without much luck. No matter what I put in the settings, when I save the configuration, it gives me a the “The configuration has been saved.” message, but the PayPal settings will then be empty. This is for any PayPal method, no matter what credentials or options I put in (so long as they pass front-end validation).

I have watched every log file I can think of, and there are no errors showing up. Not a peep. I also have tried this on my local environment and a deployed test environment, both acting the same way.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas? Not being able to test this method is definitely holding me up, and is essential for my store.

Appreciate your help! Thanks.
(I also posted this in the Magento forums, and will post any helpful info here if I find it.)

EDIT: Here's an image of what I put in, with bunk test credentials. I would expect that it would throw some kind of error, but I only get success and then a blanked out form on refresh.

[image: Form]

Comment: To clarify, I checked the Magento log files var/log/{system,exception}.log and apache/mysql/php logs.

Comment: Double check the settings are not saved in other configuration scopes just to be sure.  Is this site an upgrade or have any other paypal/payment related modules? Any specific reason it would start happening? Out of the blue? After editing local.xml? Something?

Comment: New install. First time trying to set up PayPal. I have some extensions but none that should affect Payment. I will double check.. I am periodically getting this error in Apache: [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: *snip*../app/etc/local.xml

Comment: I will check another configuration scope soon. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that this error was caused by a Core override for another bug. The override that caused the issue is explained here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/26245/viewthread/285220/

Removing said code resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache and do a reindexing.
Also do a chomd -R 777 for testing purposes, to see if it then works.

Comment: Tried them both.. no joy. Thanks for the suggestion. Edited question with an image.

Answer (score 0):

If You still have this issue,

Its because magento changed the currency support for paypal to depends on your site base currency,

I have made module that Fix this issue and allow you to use multi currency with paypal with conversion rate etc..

check https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

Comment: My store will only need one currency, USD, which PayPal supports. Is there a setting in Magento that will circumvent this problem? I have disabled all but USD, and still, when attempting to save, get a blank admin form with no error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Magneto 1.8.1, but I didn't have PayPal setup...

I had an idea, to try to save config in Internet Explorer (I usually use Chrome) and it worked!

Hope this helps!