# unable to save Paypal method settings magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, mysql, magento, paypal

I have tried the solution from here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/26245/viewthread/285220/. And then I flushed the cache as well as re-indexing the entire system, but I still can't save the PayPal method settings. When the "save config" button is clicked, it says completed, but when I checked the old default data, it is still there. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at these possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280274/paypal-settings-in-magento-1-7-0-2-wont-save?rq=1

Comment: That is the technique I tried and it did not work. Your link is a hyperlink to the original thread I have referred to above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration I found out that the values I entered and saved were indeed added to magento's database. Thus, this was an error on my part.

The saved values were not showing in the admin area of magento for good reason. What you would see is a number of dots which don't match the number of characters you entered(sometimes more). Making sense of the situation, I realize this might have been intended as a security feature; to protect your credentials from unauthorized viewing. Still, this behavior can be changed in "magento\app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\etc\system.xml" by changing the type of field you want. So instead of using "obscure" for a field, you could use e.g. "text". Doing this will show your credentials you just typed. I strongly recommend keeping it as obscure. Thanks ivanji.